# Flash CS6 input chinese text in IDE search field

Tags: flash, input, ide, fonts, cjk

We have a legacy project that uses, eck, the timeline. In older versions of Flash, I could search in the "Movie Explorer" (or the normal search) using Chinese characters.

Now, in CS6 when I paste some Chinese in the IDE input field, all it shows are the missing glyph rectangles instead of characters.

I've tried setting in the preferences, "Default Font Mapping" to MS Sans Unicode, but that's only for textfield symbols, not the IDE.

How do I change the font the IDE uses for the interface to a font that supports UTF-16 characters? Is it possible?

(Flash CS6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Windows 7 Updated to SP1. In doing so, it did not update the language packs, so any windows UI was missing the glyphs.

Solution: run windows update and install necessary language packs for SP1